# How to use a conditional for all childs in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code below is what I have been trying to do but the `dbRef.on("child_added...` executes after the ending check. I know why this is happening so how could I do a similar conditional with every child in a firebase path at once and then execute a check afterward. Thanks.

```js
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref("/ExamplePath");
let found = false;
dbRef.on("child_added", (child) => {
     if (child.val().test == testingVal) {
          console.log("Found One!");
          found = true;
     }
});

if (found) {
     console.log("Finished!");
}else{
     console.log("Nope!");
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question further.

Comment: What is `testingVal`? Share full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `child_added` handler is called for each child, and there is no way inside it to know whether this was the last child. For that you'll want to listen to the `value` event.

So one options is:

```
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref("/ExamplePath");
let found = false;
dbRef.on("child_added", (child) => {
     if (child.val().test == testingVal) {
          console.log("Found One!");
          found = true;
     }
});

dbRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    if (found) {
         console.log("Finished!");
    }else{
         console.log("Nope!");
    }
});
```

This works great, and Firebase ensures the data gets only downloaded once, despite it being passed to both listeners.

---

If you prefer you can also do the same with just a `value` listener:

```
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref("/ExamplePath");

dbRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    let found = false;
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
         if (child.val().test == testingVal) {
              console.log("Found One!");
              found = true;
         }
    });

    if (found) {
         console.log("Finished!");
    }else{
         console.log("Nope!");
    }
});
```

The result and efficiency of both approaches is the same, so you should choose whatever is most convenient for your app. For example, I prefer listening to `child_` events when I'm responsible for updating each element in the UI directly, as the `child_*` event tells me pretty directly what to do.